# String Maniuplation in C#

Tags: c#, file, console-application

I have a program that finds words within a text file and print them out. But this is a school assignment, and I need to use a certain degree of object oriented programming, like using different classes and interfaces.

So, the issue I have is that I have two public classes, that when called and adopted in the main class, with the main method, prints out the two string values I want.

The code looks like this

```
public class GetFilePath
{
    public string FilePath;

    public GetFilePath(string fn)
    {
        /// string path = "testfile.txt";
        FilePath = fn;
    }
    public void SetFilename(string NewFilePath)
    {
        FilePath = NewFilePath;
    }   
}

public class GetSearchWord
{

    public string WordSearch;
    public GetSearchWord(string st)
    {
        WordSearch = st;
    }


    public void SetSearchTerm(string NewSearchTerm)
    {
        WordSearch = NewSearchTerm;
    }
}
```

These are implemented into the main function as follows

```
        Console.Write("please enter a file to search for: ");
        // Call the constructor that has no parameters.
        GetFilePath Filepath1 = new GetFilePath("");
        Console.WriteLine(Filepath1.FilePath);
        Filepath1.SetFilename("testfile.txt");
        Console.WriteLine(Filepath1.FilePath);

        // Call the constructor that has one parameter.
        Console.Write("please enter a word to search for in the file: ");
        GetSearchWord SearchedWord1 = new GetSearchWord("");
        Console.WriteLine(SearchedWord1.WordSearch);
        SearchedWord1.SetSearchTerm("true");
        Console.WriteLine(SearchedWord1.WordSearch);
```

But I need to connect `Filepath1.FilePath` and `SearchedWord1.WordSearch` to the following strings

```
string FilePath = "";
string WordSearch = "";
```

As you can see those are null at the moment.

which are the key strings in my search function that actually searches up the lines with the words!

The FilePath and WordSearched strings are used as following

```
using (StreamReader fs = File.OpenText(FilePath))
        {
            int count = 0; //counts the number of times wordResponse is found.
            int lineNumber = 0;
            while (!fs.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = fs.ReadLine();
                lineNumber++;
                int position = line.IndexOf(WordSearch);
                if (position != -1)
                {
                    count++;
                    Console.WriteLine("Match#{0} line {1}: {2}", count, lineNumber, line);
                }
            }

            if (count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("your word was not found!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your word was found " + count + " times!");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to quit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

what I have tried doing is setting

```
string WordSearch = SearchedWord1.WordSearch;
```

as an example of what I am trying to achive since, SearchedWord1.WordSearch is currently set to "true" which is the keyword I want to search my file for.

Comment: What do you mean by connect?

Comment: Also, where in the code are those separate strings (you are not giving us a good explanation of what you need)?

Comment: I suggest you read on on [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) which is a better way to deal with getting and setting private fields in C#

Comment: If you have a getter method and a setter method, you should declare `public string FilePath;'  as private, not public.

Comment: If this is a school project, you are not using OO in a scholarly manor.

Comment: @Amorphis what is OO in a "scholarly" manner?

Comment: Object oriented in the way you are taught at schools and uni's. Objects should represent a concept or a model of something real (in real life its not always like that)

Comment: @Amorphis we'll just have to see what sorta grade I get then! Either way I solved the issue but I'll keep your feedback in mind for the future. I do feel the two classes or objects I created stand for something tangible, the terms I look for. Although they are veeeery rudimentary classes at the moment.

I do appriciate the feedback though! I'm pretty new to Stackoverflow and I am trying to figure out how best I ask questions on here. :)

Comment: @Hangfish, there is no problem with your question, but sometimes when people ask questions those who answer find other issues with their code and there is nothing wrong with that as well , albeit its more related to StackExchange Software engineering/Code Review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understood your question correctly then the following code should solve your problem(update your main code with the following):

```
Console.Write("please enter a file to search for: ");
        // Call the constructor that has no parameters.
        var filePathInput = Console.ReadLine();

        GetFilePath Filepath1 = new GetFilePath(filePathInput);
        Console.WriteLine(Filepath1.FilePath);
        Filepath1.SetFilename("testfile.txt");
        Console.WriteLine(Filepath1.FilePath);

        // Call the constructor that has one parameter.
        Console.Write("please enter a word to search for in the file: ");
        var searchWordInput = Console.ReadLine();
        GetSearchWord SearchedWord1 = new GetSearchWord(searchWordInput);
        Console.WriteLine(SearchedWord1.WordSearch);
        SearchedWord1.SetSearchTerm("true");
        Console.WriteLine(SearchedWord1.WordSearch);
```

the change is that this code is getting the input from the user...

Comment: This kinda worked, this will probably help me get the program to do exactly what I want it to do. But yeah, I changed `string FilePath = "";
string WordSearch = "";` to `var FilePath = Filepath1.FilePath;
        var WordSearch = SearchedWord1.WordSearch;` and now it works. Thank you!